# ASP.NET MVC erroring on some clients but not all

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 site that works without error in the debugger and on a few other PCs. However on some clients/pc's I just get an error message when trying to access information:

Error.An error occurred while processing your request.

Any ideas why this doesn't happen all the time and any idea how to track down the problem?

Comment: do you have some more detail on the error? Stacktrace, eventually some code?

Comment: I don't have any more information - as I said, it works fine on the debugger, but not on other clients (where no debugger is attached). Hence, no stacktrace etc. This is the problem....

Comment: find some method of logging the error (look for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569252/logging-errors-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @woldf - thanks, the link led me to Elmah which I then used to identify the problem within 2 minutes!