# Best way to log error on website

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, web

I am building website, which is using ASP.NET, MS-SQL and AJAX.
I wonder, what is the best way to log errors in the entire website?

What I was thinking about, is just create some global log class (accessible from entire application) and log errors to "asperror.txt" file using try catch blocks in asp.net.

Is this good way to track errors? Maybe there is some better ways?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you log errors (Exceptions) in your ASP.NET apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950/how-do-you-log-errors-exceptions-in-your-asp-net-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My humble opinion, and to not to reinvent the wheel, is to use [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/), which is great and easy to configure in ASP.NET.

It allows logging to Database, File, Email and so forth. It catches all unhandled exceptions and even allows you to see the last X (certain buffer is available, I believe is 500) number of messages through a web page. It even has a RSS feed if you want to subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ELMAH](http://nuget.org/packages/elmah/):

> ELMAH with initial configuration for getting started quickly. ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) is an application-wide error logging facility that is completely pluggable. It can be dynamically added to a running ASP.NET web application, or even all ASP.NET web applications on a machine, without any need for re-compilation or re-deployment.