# Show generic error message to users, but send detailed stack trace etc. to admin?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently came across this message when trying to do something on my production website:

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> *You must supply either a card or a customer id*
>
> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details**: Stripe.StripeException: You must supply either a
>   card or a customer id
>
> **Source Error**:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace**:
>
> [StripeException: You must supply either a card or a customer id]
>   Stripe.Requestor.ExecuteWebRequest(WebRequest webRequest) +238
>   Stripe.Requestor.PostString(String url) +22
>   Stripe.StripeChargeService.Create(StripeChargeCreateOptions
>   createOptions) +40
>   AwesomenessWeb.Controllers.CustomersController.PaymentPost(PurchaseType
>   purchaseType, Int32 optionID, String stripeToken) in
>   c:\a\src\AwesomenessWeb\AwesomenessWeb\Controllers\CustomersController.cs:599
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +193
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +214
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12()
>   +55    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +253
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +324
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +106
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +91    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   *) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62    System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +48
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +7 
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
>   +22    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9631764    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.19064

Is there any way all of this information can be emailed to my email address.. and a generic page will be displayed to the user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you log errors (Exceptions) in your ASP.NET apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950/how-do-you-log-errors-exceptions-in-your-asp-net-apps) (also see [Send email from Elmah?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401/send-email-from-elmah/34435#34435))

Comment: You can use [ELMAH](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). It is easy to configure it to show a generic error message to your users, but log and/or email you every detail available on the exception.